# How to get value_counts() of unique elements of a nested column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to count the unique values of a nested column of a pandas df which is the result of manuel comments.
Let's say we have the following df:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(x=["A","B","C","D"], values=["33 53 51 42 41 40 39", "33 53 51 42 41 40 39", "33 51 42 41 40 39", "33 51 42 41 40 39"]))
```

what results in:

```
    x   values
0   A   33 53 51 42 41 40 39
1   B   33 53 51 42 41 40 39
2   C   33 51 42 41 40 39
3   D   33 51 42 41 40 39
```

My two goals are the following:

1. Get the unique values of the column "values", what i figured out by applying:

```
list_unique = []
for i in range(len(df_test["values"])):
    for j in pd.Series(df_test["values"].iloc[i].split(" ")).unique():
        list_unique.append(j)
list(set(list_unique))
```

2. Furthermore it is quite interessting how often the unique values occur.

What is the best way to get something like value_counts() but for all unique elements of the nested column? What would be something like:

```
33  4
39  4
40  4
41  4
42  4
51  4
53  2
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and call [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
s = df_test["values"].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
print(s)
51    4
33    4
42    4
41    4
39    4
40    4
53    2
dtype: int64
```

If need `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = s.rename_axis('val').reset_index(name='count')
print(df1)
  val  count
0  51      4
1  33      4
2  42      4
3  41      4
4  39      4
5  40      4
6  53      2
```

Comment: That works great and also makes things easier regarding the first goal by applying .unique() after stacking. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to `str.split` the column of strings, flatten them using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and to build a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the result:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

pd.Series(Counter(chain.from_iterable(df_test['values'].str.split())))

33    4
53    2
51    4
42    4
41    4
40    4
39    4
dtype: int64
```

---

Adding timings for comparison:

```
df = pd.concat([df_test]*10_000)

%timeit pd.Series(Counter(chain.from_iterable(df['values'].str.split())))
# 79.2 ms ± 5.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df["values"].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
# 278 ms ± 29.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Sure, no worries @sl4sh :)